# OrientDB 2.2.*+ Embedded Recommended 32-bit/x86 Configuration/JVM Parameters

Tags: java, memory, jvm, 32bit-64bit, orientdb

I wanted to ask what are the recommended/required parameters to pass to OrientDB and JVM in order to run properly on 32-bit/x86 Windows?

We are running OrientDB 2.2.2 and I am seeing seeing OOM issues if we configure the Xmx + storage.diskCache.BufferSize totaling over 1.5gb. If I set the total to ~1.4gb, then behavior stabilizes a bit more. I also have to set the memory.chunk.size to 400 to see orientdb startup properly. I am trying to follow the guidelines on the performance tuning page, but it seems that most of the rhetoric assumes a 64-bit/x64 system.

Here is what we have set:

- -Xrs
- -XX:+UseG1GC
- -XX:+AggresiveOpts
- -XX:CompileThreshold=200
- -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
- -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1g (settings this to 2g causes stability issues)
- -Djna.nosys=true (per recommendation following a orientdb github issue)
- -Dstorage.wal.syncOnPageFlush=false
- -Dstorage.diskcache.bufferSize=712
- -Dmemory.chunk.size=400 (is this be required? We saw much more stable behavior once added)
- -DORIENTDB_HOME=C:\someLocation
- -DSERVERLOGS_DIR=C:\someLocation\logs
- -Xms10m
- -Xmx712m

I would like some definitive 32-bit recommendations from OrientDB if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Kazelin could you post the error into the log? Thx in advance

Comment: Hi @MichelaBonizzi, with the settings above, we aren't seeing an error. I am looking for configuration/optimization items to ensure that running on a 32-bit windows machine will not incur any processing/memory issues moving forward. I have added the Xmx and Xms values that we are currently utilizing as well. Does OrientDB staff have any recommendations?

Comment: I have the same issue. We use 32-bit Java for more universal compatibility and updating OrientDB to 2.2.x (which uses direct memory) is making life difficult. Can the direct memory stuff be turned off for 32-bit systems with small amounts of memory (< 2GB)?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to get 32-bit OrientDB running on Windows reliably with the following changes. I've noticed the performance isn't quite as good as with OrientDB 2.0, likely because OrientDB now assumes much more memory and 32-bit Java cannot deliver.

In orientdb-server-config.xml:

1. A smaller WAL.

   - `<entry value="true" name="storage.useWAL"/>`
   - `<entry value="32" name="storage.wal.maxSegmentSize"/>`
   - `<entry value="256" name="storage.wal.maxSize"/>`
2. A smaller memory chunk size (default is MAX_INT 2147483647).

   - `<entry name="memory.chunk.size" value="134217728"/>`

In JVM parameters:

1. A max heap of 512MB.

   - `-Xmx512m`
2. Max direct memory greater than heap but low enough to not run out of memory.

   - `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=640m`